# Is there any specific use of Hidden Markov models in physics?

Tags: hidden-markov-model

I have just discovered what is a HMM and I think it has pretty good predictive power and I thought whether they can be used in any specific branch of physics.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for weather forecasting, see https://towardsdatascience.com/predicting-the-weather-with-markov-chains-a34735f0c4df